# How to get details of other users using screenname in linqtotwitter(version 2.1.11)

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I am using following code but it only shows for my account only i want to get details of others using screenname so i can get friendscount of that user (v2.1.11)

```
  var twitterCtx = new LinqToTwitter.TwitterContext(auth);

            var accounts =
            from acct in twitterCtx.Account
            where acct.Type == AccountType.VerifyCredentials
            select acct;

            Account account = accounts.SingleOrDefault();


            User user = account.User;
            Status tweet = user.Status ?? new Status();
            Console.WriteLine(
                "User ID: {0}\nScreen Name: {1}\nTweet: {2}\n Tweet ID: {3}",
                 user.Identifier.ID,
                 user.Identifier.ScreenName,
                 tweet.Text,
                 tweet.StatusID);

            string followerscount = user.FriendsCount.ToString();
            string tweetscount = user.StatusesCount.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine("Account credentials are verified.");
```

Comment: Maybe useful https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples

Answer (score 2):

The Twitter API only offers that. There isn't a way to read anyone's personal data without their approval.

Comment: ok but i can fetch followers,tweets with my twitter credentials using screen name sorry if i misunderstood tht...

Comment: i want to fetch tweets details using screenname how can i loop through and save in database i gone through your article (Working with Timelines with LINQ to Twitter) but i'm not understood how to use since_id and max_id